# Не работает кнопка при помещении в другой блок

Tags: html, css

Есть окно старта игры, я хочу чтобы оно выравнивалось посередине относительно самого контейнера с игрой. Кнопка в окне работает, когда окно помещено в body, но когда оно помещено в .container - перестает работать.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(img/body.jpg);
}
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: cyan;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -2;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.canvas {
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}
.startWindow {
  border: 5px solid green;
  background-image: url(img/logo.png);
  width: 480px;
  height: 320px;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.start {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 25px;
  background-color: #32CD32;
  border-color: green;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px green;
}
.start:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="startWindow">
    <button class="start">Let's go!</button>
  </div>
  <div class="gameOverWindow">
    <button class="start">Try again!</button>
  </div>
  <p class="score">Score:</p>
  <div class="canvas">
    <canvas width="800" height="600" id="screen"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="highscores"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Все из-за z-index скорее всего. Попробуй z-index сделать больше чем у body

Answer (score 1):

Поменял html и у `canvas` удалил `position: relative;`, теперь `.startWindow`, `.gameOverWindow` и `.start` будут позиционироваться относительно `.canvas`.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(img/body.jpg);
}
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: cyan;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: -2;
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
}
.canvas {
  float: left;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}
.startWindow {
  border: 5px solid green;
  background-image: url(img/logo.png);
  width: 480px;
  height: 320px;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.start {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 25px;
  background-color: #32CD32;
  border-color: green;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px green;
}
.start:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="score">Score:</p>
  <div class="canvas">
    <canvas width="800" height="600" id="screen"></canvas>
    <div class="startWindow">
      <button class="start">Let's go!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="gameOverWindow">
      <button class="start">Try again!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="highscores"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Только проблема в том, что кнопка не кликабельна

Comment: В примере кода кнопка тоже не кликабельна, я на это не стал обращаться внимания т.к. вопрос про другое.

Comment: вопрос был в первую очередь из-за того, что кнопка перестает быть кликабельной